# playEffect] problem with effect

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hi 
I am trying to make car engine sound by using SimpleAudioEngine .

i can use this engine on my menu loop without problem 
this works fine 
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"menuLoop.wav"];

But i cannot use any of playEffect metods

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"engine.wav"];

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"engine.wav" pitch:0.5f pan:0.6f gain:1.0f];

both of them dont working on simulator or device

Plz help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your wave file is using format that is supported by CocosDenshion. as explained here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion:faq#i_ve_got_some_wave_files_but_they_don_t_work_what_can_i_do

You can try using afconvert tool to fix the file:

```
afconvert -v -f WAVE -d LEI16 notworking.wav working.wav
```